# Opencv crosscompile with ffmpeg and other 3rdparty for arm board

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, arm

After buliding Qt5.5.1 for my arm board sucessfully, I am taking up to crosscompile opencv. Here are the steps:

First, I crosscompile 3rdparty:

a.libz

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ sudo tar -zvxf zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ cd zlib-1.2.8
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/zlib-1.2.8$ sudo ./configure --prefix=/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely -shared
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/zlib-1.2.8$ sudo vi Makefile
```

and etit Makefile in some details:

```
#Makefile
CC=/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
LDSHARED= /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libz.so.1,--version-script,zlib.map
AR=/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
RANLIB=arm-linux-ranlib
```

the last step is run make and make install:

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/zlib-1.2.8$ sudo make
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/zlib-1.2.8$ sudo make install
```

b.libjpeg

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ sudo tar -zvxf jpegsrc.v9.tar.gz
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ cd jpeg-9
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/jpeg-9$ sudo CC=/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc ./configure --host=arm-linux --prefix=/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely --enable-shared --enable-static
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/jpeg-9$ sudo make
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/jpeg-9$ sudo make install
```

c.libpng

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ sudo xz -d libpng-1.6.29.tar.xz
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ sudo tar -xvf libpng-1.6.29.tar
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ cd libpng-1.6.29
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/libpng-1.6.29$ sudo CC=/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc ./configure --host=arm-linux --prefix=/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely --enable-shared --enable-static
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/libpng-1.6.29$ sudo make
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/libpng-1.6.29$ sudo make install
```

d.yasm

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ sudo tar -zvxf yasm-1.3.0.tar.gz
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ cd yasm-1.3.0
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/yasm-1.3.0$ sudo CC=/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc ./configure --prefix=/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely --host=arm-linux
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/yasm-1.3.0$ sudo make
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/yasm-1.3.0$ sudo make install
```

e.libx264

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ sudo tar -jxvf last_x264.tar.bz2
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ cd x264-snapshot-20170612-2245 
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/x264-snapshot-20170612-2245$ sudo CC=/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc ./configure --enable-shared --host=arm-linux --disable-asm --prefix=/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/x264-snapshot-20170612-2245$ sudo make
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/x264-snapshot-20170612-2245$ sudo make install
```

f.libxvid

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ cd xvidcore-1.3.3
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/xvidcore-1.3.3$ cd build/generic
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/xvidcore-1.3.3/build/generic$ sudo CC=/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc ./configure --prefix=/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely --host=arm-linux  --disable-assembly
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/xvidcore-1.3.3/build/generic$ sudo make
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/xvidcore-1.3.3/build/generic$ sudo make install
```

g.ffmpeg

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ sudo tar -jvxf ffmpeg-3.3.2.tar.bz2
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ cd ffmpeg-3.3.2
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/ffmpeg-3.3.2$
sudo ./configure --prefix=/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-gpl --enable-cross-compile  --arch=arm --disable-stripping --target-os=linux --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --cc=/home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc --enable-swscale --extra-ldflags=-L/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib --extra-cflags=-I/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/include
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/ffmpeg-3.3.2$ sudo make
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/ffmpeg-3.3.2$ sudo make install
```

There is no problem in 3rdparty crosscompile.
Next, opencv crosscompile:

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ sudo unzip opencv-3.1.0.zip
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk$ cd opencv-3.1.0
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0$ sudo mkdir BuildOpencv
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0$ cd BuildOpencv
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/BuildOpencv$ sudo vim toolchain.cmake
#toolchain.cmake
###########user defined#############
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux )
set( CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc )
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-g++ )
###########user defined#############
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely)
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER )
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set( CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
######################################
```

Then I run cmake:

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/BuildOpencv$ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain.cmake ../
```

Here is the result：

```
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 45 (405)
-- Found ZLIB: /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing:  TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARIES) (found version "1.900.1")
-- Found ZLIB: /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   package 'gtk+-3.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libavresample'
--   package 'libavresample' not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libgphoto2'
 --   package 'libgphoto2' not found
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES) (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.7")
-- Cannot probe for Python/Numpy support (because we are cross-compiling OpenCV)
-- If you want to enable Python/Numpy support, set the following variables:
--   PYTHON2_INCLUDE_PATH
--   PYTHON2_LIBRARIES
--   PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS
--   PYTHON3_INCLUDE_PATH
--   PYTHON3_LIBRARIES
--   PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.4 (found suitable version "3.4.3", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES) (Required is at least version "3.4")
-- Cannot probe for Python/Numpy support (because we are cross-compiling OpenCV)
-- If you want to enable Python/Numpy support, set the following variables:
--   PYTHON2_INCLUDE_PATH
--   PYTHON2_LIBRARIES
--   PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS
--   PYTHON3_INCLUDE_PATH
--   PYTHON3_LIBRARIES
--   PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0 
=====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.16.0-77-generic i686
--     Target:                      Linux arm
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-g++  (ver 4.5.1)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /home/newdisk/optnew/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/bin/arm-linux-gcc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libjpeg.so /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libpng.so /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libz.so gtk-x11-2.0 gdk-x11-2.0 atk-1.0 gio-2.0 pangoft2-1.0 pangocairo-1.0 gdk_pixbuf-2.0 cairo pango-1.0 fontconfig gobject-2.0 freetype gthread-2.0 glib-2.0 dc1394 v4l1 v4l2 avcodec avformat avutil swscale dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libwebp libtiff libjasper IlmImf
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml photo video imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect superres ts features2d calib3d stitching videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 python3 viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.23)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.40.2)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libjpeg.so (ver 90)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libpng.so (ver 1.6.29)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.1)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 54.35.1)
--       format:                    YES (ver 54.20.4)
--       util:                      YES (ver 52.3.0)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 2.1.1)
--       resample:                  NO
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 0.8.8) / libv4l2 (ver 0.8.8)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--      Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.3)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
--     PlantUML:                    NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/BuildOpencv/install
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/BuildOpencv
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/BuildOpencv
```

After configuring and generating, run cmake-gui:

```
lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/BuildOpencv$ sudo cmake-gui

Src:/home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0
Build:/home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/BuildOpencv

CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-arm

Don't choose these items:
WITH_CUDA
WITH_GTK
WITH_1394
WITH_GSTREAMER
WITH_LIBV4L 
WITH_TIFF
BUILD_OPENEXR
WITH_OPENEXR
WITH_OPENCL

Configure and generate.

lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/BuildOpencv$ sudo vi CMakeCache.txt
#CMakeCache.txt
//Flags used by the linker.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=-lpthread -lrt

lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:/home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/BuildOpencv$ sudo make
```

Fianlly,I got these errors:

```
[ 27%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_mjpeg_decoder.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_v4l.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o
In file included from /home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:65:0,
             from /home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/home/newdisk/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/ffmpeg_codecs.hpp:77:36: fatal error: libavformat/avformat.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

While the file libavformat/avformat.h does exits in my directory
    /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/include

Why can cmake find lib directory

```
-- Found ZLIB: /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3")
```

but cannot find include directory?

```
/home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/include
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding extra two lines to file `toolchain.cmake`
`INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/include )`,`LINK_DIRECTORIES( /home/newdisk/optnew/opencv-rely/lib )`. Sincerely hope that anyone will explain it more clearly